# C++11 Overloading operator for in class placed enum class

Tags: c++, class, c++11, enums

this is my first try to use enum classes for my projects, but I have the problem that I can't compile my code if the enum class is placed inside of another class.
I try to define the operator overloading like my example and I try to do it outside, too.
All works fine if I place the enum class outside the class.
Whats wrong? How to overloading the operator if I what to use it placed in an class?

```
#include <cstdint>

namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
    public:
        enum class MyEnum_t
        {
            VALUE_0 = 0x0,
            VALUE_1 = 0x1,
            VALUE_2 = 0x2,
            VALUE_3 = 0x4,
            VALUE_4 = 0x8 
       };

        inline MyEnum_t &operator|(MyEnum_t lhs, MyEnum_t rhs)
        {
            return static_cast<MyEnum_t>(static_cast<std::uint8_t>(lhs) | static_cast<std::uint8_t>(rhs));
        }
}

int main()
{
    MyNamespace::MyClass::MyEnum_t test = MyNamespace::MyClass::MyEnum_t::VALUE_0;

    test = MyNamespace::MyClass:MyEnum_t::VALUE_1 | MyNamespace::MyClass::MyEnum_t::VALUE_2;

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: *"I can't compile my code"*, so provide error message.

Comment: Your class definition is missing a closing brace and a semi-colon. It's better to sort these things out before posting, so the code exhibits just the problem you are asking about.

Comment: `MyClass::MyEnum_t &operator|(MyClass::MyEnum_t lhs, MyClass::MyEnum_t rhs)` should be placed outside the class.

Answer (score 3):

The enum class can be inside another class, but the operator definition must be at namespace scope.

Also note that the operator is computing a new value and as such, it cannot return a reference, as there would be nothing to which the reference could bind. It should return by value instead.

In total:

```
namespace MyNamespace
{
    class MyClass
    {
    public:
        enum class MyEnum_t
        {
            VALUE_0 = 0x0,
            VALUE_1 = 0x1,
            VALUE_2 = 0x2,
            VALUE_3 = 0x4,
            VALUE_4 = 0x8 
       };
    };

    inline MyClass::MyEnum_t operator|(MyClass::MyEnum_t lhs, MyClass::MyEnum_t rhs)
    {
       return static_cast<MyEnum_t>(static_cast<std::uint8_t>(lhs) | static_cast<std::uint8_t>(rhs));
    }
}
```

Comment: Might wanna fix the return type of the operator

Comment: I agree with you that this must be the correct way to do it but it doesn't compile.
If I try to compile it I got the message:
"error: ‘MyEnum_t’ does not name a type"
If I try to fix the return value adding "MyClass::" I got:
"error: cannot bind non-const lvalue reference of type ‘MyNamespace::MyClass::MyEnum_t&’ to an rvalue of type ‘MyNamespace::MyClass::MyEnum_t’"

Comment: @Mnemonic That's because of the reference, as StoryTeller correctly pointed out. Answer edited.

Comment: @Angew One thing was wrong in your solution. The scope of the return value. After fixing that its compiles. Thank you.

Comment: @Mnemonic "One thing was wrong in your solution": well, it was just copy-pasted from the Q, so it wasn't really "my" solution. I just didn't notice, because the `&` is placed in an unusual place (it's more commonly placed by the type, not by the function name). Anyway, that's what I mentioned as edited in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

I would write it as:

```
class MyClass
{
public:
    enum class MyEnum_t
    {
        VALUE_0 = 0x0,
        VALUE_1 = 0x1,
        VALUE_2 = 0x2,
        VALUE_3 = 0x4,
        VALUE_4 = 0x8,
    };

    friend MyEnum_t operator|(MyEnum_t lhs, MyEnum_t rhs)
    {
        using UT = std::underlying_type<MyEnum_t>::type;
        return static_cast<MyEnum_t>(static_cast<UT>(lhs) | static_cast<UT>(rhs));
    }
};
```

This way, it no longer matters whether or not `MyClass` is in a `namespace`, and the correct `underlying_type` is used to perform the bitwise math.

Answer (score 1):

Fixed code for the operator:

```
inline MyClass::MyEnum_t operator|(MyClass::MyEnum_t lhs, MyClass::MyEnum_t rhs)
{
    return static_cast<MyClass::MyEnum_t>(static_cast<std::uint8_t>(lhs) | static_cast<std::uint8_t>(rhs));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As you wrote your following main() code line:

test = MyNamespace::MyClass:MyEnum_t::VALUE_1 | MyNamespace::MyClass::MyEnum_t::VALUE_2;

It will expect namespace operator, so the operator should be placed outside the MyClass (but within the MyNamespace):

```
MyClass::MyEnum_t operator|(MyClass::MyEnum_t lhs, MyClass::MyEnum_t rhs)
{
    return static_cast<MyClass::MyEnum_t>(static_cast<std::uint8_t>(lhs) | static_cast<std::uint8_t>(rhs));
}
```

also, as stated in above answer you can not return a temporary memory (as reference), so either return by-value or define static variable in the operator and return it.